# Keep the right value if row value duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A'],
                   'b': ['B', 'D'],
                   'c': ['C', 'C'],
                   'd': ['D', 'D']},
                   index=[0, 1])
```

I would like to keep the right cell if the row has the same value

Desire Output

```
  0  1
0    A
1 B  D
2    C
3    D
```

I have tried `df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(pd.unique, df.values)))`
but it will push the values to the nearest left which is not my desired output.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A'],
                   'b': ['B', 'D'],
                   'c': ['C', 'C'],
                   'd': ['D', 'D']},
                   index=[0, 1])

df=df.T #Transposing the dataframe

def SameValue(row):
    if row[0] == row[1]:
        return ''        #If the rows match return an empty string
    else:
        return row[0]    #If the rows do not match return the original value


df[0] = df.apply(SameValue, axis=1)   #Apply the SameValue function on the dataframe

print(df)
```

Please let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to this do would be:

```
df = df.T # Transpose of the datafame
df.loc[df[0]==df[1],0] = '' # Find where column 0 and 1 are equal and change the value of column 0 to empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

Used pythonic way instead of pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A'],
                   'b': ['B', 'D'],
                   'c': ['C', 'C'],
                   'd': ['D', 'D']},
                   index=[0, 1])
 

data_in_dict = df.to_dict()
for key in data_in_dict:
   if data_in_dict[key][0] == data_in_dict[key][1]
      data_in_dict[key][0] = ''

final_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data_in_dict, index=[0,1])
print(final_data_frame.T)
```